# Locate pc on local network

Tags: networking, ip, router, switching

We have 10000 or more computers in our network. We want to find the computer with a certain ip. Is there way to learn the switch that the computer is connected to? We have only one router in our network.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and get the Mac Address from the Computer then. Depending on what kind of switches you have you could telnet into the switch and find out if the Mac address is connected through there.  Just an Idea I would comment but do not have the privilege to.